# How to deserialize json with a string-url name-value pair

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I have json response in the form

```
 {
  "total": 782,
  "category": {
    "id": 1120,
    "name": "Computers & Programming"
  },
  "experts": [
    {
      "id": 385816,
      "name": "Master Z",
      "title": "Mr",
      "description": " Expert in C++",
      "profile": "http://...com/experts.svc/1.0/385816/..../json?.."                        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to parse everything else in the experts[] array except "profile" whose value "http://...com/experts.svc/1.0/385816/..../json?.." has the following json response

```
{
  "id": 385816,
  "name": "Master Z",
  "title": "",
  "reviewsCount": 15359,
  "averageRating": 4.87,
  "status": 4,
  "fee": 19.99,
  "languages": "English",
  "category": {
    "id": 1120,
    "name": "Computers & Programming"
  }
}
```

The models used are as follows
1. main pojo:

```
public class ExpertObj
{
    private String total;

    private Category category;

    private Experts[] experts;    

}
```

2. Category pojo:

   public class Category
   {

   private String id;
   private String name;

   }

3.Experts array pojo:

```
   public class Experts
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String profile;
}
```

Am using Retrift 2.

```
private RestManager mManager;
List<Expert> mExperts = new ArrayList<>();

....

Call<ExpertsObj> call = mManager.getExpertsService().listAllExperts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ExpertsObj>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ExpertsObj> call, Response<ExpertsObj> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    ExpertsObj expertsObj = response.body();

                    mExperts = expertsObj.getExperts();
....}
```

At a loss how to parse the profile-url name-value pair and display the results in a detail layout in android.
Any help is appreciated.
New in android. Please excuse if anything is not explained properly.

Comment: _I am able to parse everything else in the experts[] array except "profile"_   can you also add this part of your code to your question?

Comment: what did you even tried to do so far? show us code.

Comment: petey-added the retrofit portion

Comment: @KevinAvignon Tried creating a Profile object class

Comment: @KevinAvignon Tried creating a Profile object class, but getting illegal state exception

Comment: @KevinAvignon remove one of the ' }' below "profile" from first json response.