# ANDROID JSON Retrieve multiple values from a nested key

Tags: java, android, json

First I want to retrieve all the rate values which are nested in the rating name and assume i will not know how many number of ratings in there so there should be some kind of loop that check them. The json object is shown below.

```
{
  "restaurant": [
    {
      "restaurantId": "1",
      "restaurantName": "Restaurant A",
      "area": "Skudai",
      "state": "Johor",
      "rating": [
        {
          "ratingId": "1",
          "rate": "5",
          "comment": null,
          "userId": "15"
        },
        {
          "ratingId": "2",
          "rate": "4",
          "comment": null,
          "userId": "14"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "restaurantId": "2",
      "restaurantName": "Restaurant 2",
      "area": "Skudai",
      "state": "Johor",
      "rating": null
    }
  ],
  "success": 1
}
```

Below is the code which seems not quite right at the retrieveng part in the while loop. For the JSONObject parameter in the getAverage, i already take the first restaurant only which is Restaurant A, Restaurant 2 is not included.

```
public int getAverage(JSONObject jsonObject){
    int average = 0, count = 0;

    while (jsonObject.has("rate")){
        average += Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("rate"));
        count++;
    }

    average /= count;

    return  average;
}
```

How do I retrieve the multiples values of rate from the nested rating using optString() to calculate the average or should I use other way to retrieve it?

Comment: where is your code??? did you tried something ??

Comment: Copy json response, paste to http://json2csharp.com, it gives you classes as C#, convert the classes to Java, use GSON to parse JSON. If you cant, pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625488/how-to-deserialize-json-with-a-string-url-name-value-pair/36625899#36625899

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library you can parse the json string to get all "rating" for each restaurant.

Example :

```
   try{
       JSONObject o = new JSONObject(json);
       JSONArray restaurants = o.getJSONArray("restaurant");
       for(int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++){
           JSONObject restaurant = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
           JSONArray ratings = restaurant.getJSONArray("rating");
           for(int j = 0; j < ratings.length(); j++){
               JSONObject rating = ratings.getJSONObject(j);
               String ratingId = rating.getString("ratingId");
               Log.d("TestJson ratingId", ratingId);
               String rate = rating.optString("rate");
               Log.d("TestJson rate", rate);
           }
       }
   }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Here, we have take only single value for ratingId and rate. If we need all id and rate then??

Comment: You just have to create a collection associated to the Restaurant and within the for loop add each value to the collection...

Comment: collection like getter setter methods on a class\

Comment: yes create an object `Rating` with attributes `id`, `rate` and setter/getter... and create a `List<Rating>`to store the values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for references:

```
                ArrayList<DrawerCategory> list = new ArrayList<DrawerCategory>();
                ArrayList<DrawerSubCategory> ch_list;
                JSONArray jArray = root.getJSONArray("restaurant");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DrawerCategory gru = new DrawerCategory();
                  gru.setrestaurantId(jObject.getString("restaurantId"));
                  .
                  .
                  if (jObject.getString("rating").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                        ch_list = new ArrayList<DrawerSubCategory>();
                        DrawerSubCategory ch = new DrawerSubCategory();
                        ch.setName(jObject.getString("rating"));
                        ch_list.add(ch);
                        gru.setItems(ch_list);
                    } else {
                  JSONArray jArray1 = jObject.getJSONArray("rating");
                        ch_list = new ArrayList<DrawerSubCategory>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject jObject1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                            DrawerSubCategory ch = new DrawerSubCategory();
                            ch.setratingId(jObject1.getString("ratingId"));
                             .
                             .
                            ch_list.add(ch);
                            gru.setItems(ch_list);
                        }
                    }
                    list.add(gru);
                }
```

Here, DrawerCategory , DrawerSubCategory is item class that contains getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Google has already made library.**

You don't need to write loops and all. Better is you should use **Java Class(Model/POJO)** serialization/deserialization library [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
 which converts you class to **JSON/JSONArray** automatically.

And please don't practice of writing long `for` loops. I have many times use to parse class with array using **gson** only.

Help if your are using android studio [GSON with studio](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/json-pojo-using-gson-android-studio)